# How can i import a file with php and keep its indentations?

Tags: php, file, import

so I am currently writing a script in php. Therefore i need to import a file into the script. The file contains many indentations which are very important.
When i import it as a string or as an array the indentations are lost.
What can I do or how should I import the file ?

greetings

edit:

```
$file_content = file_get_contents( 'D:/XAMPP/htdocs/158400.log' );
```

Inside this log file are various unnecessary warnings and erros and only a few i need. The plan is to extract the errors i need and send them via email to myself. The whole email script is already done, i only need the content for the email body.
The error log looks like this: (example)

```
ERROR: in process 345 (C::/example/ex/..) in thread 454 at 12.5.2022 8:20:03
    important error log
    important error log
    important error log
unnecessary next logs 
....
```

So my Idea is to detect the key words (such as ERROR) and send all the lines with the email that are in indented under the ERROR word.
There begins the problem. When i input the file with file get contents all indentations get lost, wheather its a string or an array.
So what can i do about that ?
I hope this time my question is better formulated, sorry guys :)

Comment: The indentations MAY be lost when you are actually outputting the data, we'd need to see how you are doing that to tell, but you've not shared any code.

Comment: I need the indentations in the script itself, not in the output.
Its a .log file and my script is there to filter out the important sequences from the log file. So the indentations are for the script to know what part is important and what part it can delet. Thats what i need. I hope you understand what i mean :')

Comment: Well the indentations shouldn't just be lost when you are importing the file. Again, we need to see exactly what you are doing to help you at all.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't be discouraged, but the way your question is formulated right now it is not very easy to understand what the problem is. In order to make it easier for people to help you, I would suggest that you try to write a very small program that reproduces the error. Then, post the program, together with the output you would expect and also the output you are actually getting.

Comment: sorry for that im new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't be sorry! Breathe and enjoy the journey! :) And give it one more try!

Comment: Most likely, you haven't realised that HTML collapses consecutive spaces and line feeds into a single white space.

Comment: And there is no way to bypass that ?